# Why python socket server accept only 5840 characters in a time?

Tags: java, python, sockets, network-programming

I created python socket server. I accepted **65536** bytes in one request.

I sent **10000** characters string from Java socket client using **BufferedWriter** to python socket server.

Python socket server accepted only **5840** characters.

Is there any size limitation in Java BufferedWriter?
Is there any size limitation in python socket?

Here, it is my python socket server and Java socket client program code.

**Python Socket Server**

```
    import socket    

    serversocket = socket.socket(
        socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

    host = socket.gethostname()
    print (host)

    port = 9999                                           

    serversocket.bind(("", port))                                  
    serversocket.listen(7)  
    print ("Server is listening client request....")

    while True:
        print ("It is true.....")
        clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
        client_msg = clientsocket.recv(65536).decode()
        print (len(client_msg))
        print (client_msg)
```

**Java Socket Client**

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String serverName = "192.168.1.99";
        int port = 9999;

        try {
            String st = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                st = st + "Hello";
            }

            System.out.println(st.length());

            Socket socket = new Socket(serverName, port);
            OutputStream outstream = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            bw.write(st);
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            osw.close();
            outstream.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly it's `4 * (Ethernet MTU - IP header - TCP header)`.

Comment: TCP writes a stream of bytes, not messages.  The number of bytes you get from a single read could 1 or many and you cannot assume it has any relationship to the number of bytes written. Once you read all data, only then do you have everything.